# Create function with names from data frame

Tags: r, function

I am using fitDist from GAMLSS to fit distribution to each of the 120 columns I have in my dataframe as shown here:

```
my_list <- list()
for (i in 1: ncol(df)) {
my_list[[i]] <- fitDist(df[,i], type = "realAll")
}
```

Now assuming the first fitted distribution is GG (Generalized Gamma), I create the functions:

```
colname <- function(p) qGG(p, ...)
```

Here is my question: is there a nice way of doing this for all the 120 columns of the dataframe without typing cycling through each column and creating the function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, but I'm not sure how efficient it is.
First, I create your list by using `lapply` instead of a `for` loop.

```
my_list<- lapply(df, function(x) fitDist(x, type = "realAll"))
```

Then I modify your function, by doing a lot of string manipulations, so we can get to the desired outcome. The main idea is that from `my_list`, we extract the relevant information, i.e. the distribution and the parameters, and then create a character string with that info, and finally we execute it.

```
colname<- function(p, my_list){
  functions<- sapply(my_list, function(x) names(x$fits[1]))
  inputs<- lapply(my_list, function(x) x$parameters)
  parameters<- lapply(seq_along(1:length(inputs)), function(x) my_list[[x]][inputs[[x]]]))
  arguments<- lapply(parameters, function(x) paste0(names(x), "=", x))
  name<- sapply(seq_along(1:length(functions)), function(x) paste0("q", functions[x], "(", paste(p, paste(arguments[[x]], collapse=","), sep=","),")", sep=""))
  colname<- sapply(name, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
}
```

I am sure there are ways to make it faster, so any comments would be greatly appreciated. Also, given that you didn't provide any reproducible example, I cannot be 100% sure it works the way you want it to.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: @MeR, I'm very happy to help! Please consider marking it as accepted, so that it declutters the "unanswered" questions page. Thank you!